# Dependency between perl modules

Tags: perl, perl-module

Suppose I have three perl modules as given below :

Test.pm

```
package Test;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Check;  
our $data = Check->getX;
1;
```

Initialize.pm

```
package Initialize;
use Check;
use Test;

Check->setX(10);
our $t = $Test::data;
print $t;
1;
```

Check.pm

```
 package Check; 
 my $x = 12;

 sub setX {    
       my ($self,$value) = @_;
       $x = $value; 
 }

 sub getX 
 {    
       return $x; 
 } 
 1;
```

Now, when I run Initialize.pm, I am initializing $x in Check.pm to 10 and $x is assigned to $data in Test.pm. But the the actual valuethat is assigned to $data is 12 which is the initial value given in Check.pm.

**So, When are the global variables initialized in perl? How can I enforce that the new value set by me in the Initialize.pm to x is what is loaded into $data?**

Now if I replace the statement use Test in Initalize.pm with require Test;  and move the statement Check->setX(10) before this require statement then $data is correctly initialized to the new value 10. **What is it that is happening differently in this case ?**

Comment: I suggest that you not call Test.pm that.  Test.pm is a core module that ships with Perl.  It looks like it's not shipping now, and I don't know when it stopped getting shipped, but I'd be wary of conflicts with Test.pm in older Perls.

Comment: This is not real object-oriented programming because you don't have any objects: the only methods are class methods. You should really have just simple subroutines instead of dressing things up as OO code when it isn't. Also, it looks like `Initialize.pm` is a *program* (if it's a module you shouldn't be running it) so it should be called `main.pl` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general modules have little or no executable code. Object-oriented modules just define the object methods, and sometimes some class data.

When you `use Test` the whole of `Test.pm` is compiled and executed, so the value of `$data` is set at this point.

The call to `setX` happens straight afterwards, but is too late to affect the asignment of `$data`.

As I said in my comment your code has a very odd structure, and modules shouldn't have a time dependency on each other at all. You should really remove all executable statements from your modules, but to force your code to do what you want you can write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Check;
BEGIN {
  Check->setX(10);
}
use Test;

our $t = $Test::data;
print $t;
```

But don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Perl executes a use statement prior to executing anything else in the file.
So the execution order is:

1. `use Check;`

   1. `$x = 12;`
2. `use Test;`

   1. `use Check;` -This only does importing as the file is already executed
   2. `$data = Check->getX();`
3. `Check->setX(10);`

If you replace `use` with `require` the instruction is evaluated at the same time as the rest of the instructions and if you move `Check->setX(10);` before the require it will be evaluated before the get in Test

Comment: When should we use require? Is it ok to use that here?

Comment: Its fine to use require so long as you are not importing subroutines. Here it would help clarify the loading order.

Comment: Ordinarily your shouldn't use `require` at all. Almost always you want `use` unless you are aiming for an unusual loading sequence. `use` doesn't do what you want here because you haven't written proper modules (contining just declarations and definitions, and nothing executable).